# Recursion/looping of rules in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to bootstrap a hmm training, thus I need to loop through a few rules a couple of times. My idea was to do this:

```
dict={'boot1':'init', 'boot2':'boot1', 'final':'boot2'} # Define the workflow


rule a_rule_to_initialize_and_make_the_first_input
    output:
        'init_hmm'

rule make_model:
    input:
        '{0}_hmm'.format(dict[{run}]) # Create the loop by referencing the dict.
    output:
        '{run}_training_data'

rule train:
     input:
         '{run}_training_data'
     output:
         '{run}_hmm'
```

However, I can't access the wildcard {run} in the format function. Any hints as how I could get a hold of {run} within the input line. Or maybe a better way of performing the iteration?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do the iteration, but the reason you can't access run is because wildcards aren't parsed unless they're in a string directly in the list of inputs or outputs. Snakemake lets you define lambda functions that get passed a wildcards object, so you need to do:

```
input:
    lambda wildcards: '{0}_hmm'.format(dict[wildcards.run])
```